# Two way mutual SSL authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, package, private-key

https://www.naschenweng.info/2018/02/01/java-mutual-ssl-authentication-2-way-ssl-authentication/

I tried implementing the "SSLMutualAuthTest" code in the above link. But it has a function 'PrivateKeyStrategy()' which is currently deprecated in the java version-8. I am not able to find a alternate function for it.

Comment: Why do you think `PrivateKeyStrategy` is depricated? Where do you see that written?

Comment: When adding it to a java program it is giving the error as function deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.apache.http.ssl.PrivateKeyStrategy` instead. It seems the interface has moved from the `httpclient` library to `httpcore` library.